# Java.nio Channels and TLS

Tags: java, nio, ssl, socketchannel

How do I secure a Java `SocketChannel`, `ServerSocketChannel` or, perhaps even, a `DatagramChannel` with TLS?

I know that there are some frameworks ([#1](http://netty.io/) [#2](http://www.restlet.org/)) that advertise to be able, but I want to know if it is possible to achieve this with the pure Java standard library alone.

Comment: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.net.ssl/client.html

Comment: @MauricioLinhares: these examples are for `SSLSocket`s, not NIO.

Answer (score 22):

You need to use the [`SSLEngine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLEngine.html), as documented in [Non-blocking I/O with SSLEngine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#SSLENG). The libraries you mention use it or use libraries that use it.

(Note that this is notoriously difficult to use.)

You may find these links interesting:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3930854/372643) (which also contains a link to a book chapter).
- [Notes from Jean-François Arcand](http://jfarcand.wordpress.com/2006/09/21/tricks-and-tips-with-nio-part-v-ssl-and-nio-friend-or-foe/) who implemented it in [Grizzly](http://grizzly.java.net).
- An [example](http://java.net/jira/browse/GRIZZLY-416) of the type of problems you can get with asynchronous SSL/TLS.
- Getting familiar with the problems mentioned in these [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6425509/372643) should also be relevant (in particular, how to deal with them in async mode).
- The [Simple Framework](http://www.simpleframework.org) also has support for async SSL/TLS.

---

For Datagrams, you should look into using [DTLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datagram_Transport_Layer_Security) instead of TLS. I'm not sure of its implementation status in Java, but you could dig through the archives of the `java.openjdk.security.devel` mailing list.

Answer (score 9):

You need to use [SSLEngine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLEngine.html) and do the handshake manually using that state machine. SSL/TLS is implemented on top of TCP so you can not use it directly on top of a `DatagramChannel`.

The article [Non-blocking I/O with SSLEngine](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.70.doc/security-component/jsse2Docs/ssleng.html) may be helpful.

Comment: The link for O'reilly is dead it seems

Answer (score 6):

As Bruno correctly mentions, the standard way of doing that is using SSLEngine. But that class is *seriously* hard to use.

I came across the same problem some time ago and ended up writing my own library. There are some examples out there and of course there is also the code inside projects like Netty, etc. But neither option is robust or easily reusable.

[TLS Channel](https://github.com/marianobarrios/tls-channel) wraps an SSLEngine in a ByteBuffer and allows to use it just like normal SocketChannels.

Comment: Nice! Any plans to support AsynchronousSocketChannel in that library?

Comment: @jyemin, seems doable and should be possible justs as an added layer on top of the existing interface. Somehow we would need to wrap a selector loop [like the one we have already as a test](https://github.com/marianobarrios/tls-channel/blob/master/src/test/scala/tlschannel/helpers/NonBlockingLoops.scala). Pull requests welcome! :-)

Comment: @jyemin, hope it's not too late, but the [latest release](https://github.com/marianobarrios/tls-channel/releases/tag/0.2.0) included asynchronoust channel support.