# How can I add encryption to Java NIO?

Tags: java, encryption, nio, encryption-asymmetric

I'm supposed to add asymmetric encryption to an application with Client <-> Server architecture using Java NIO.

I have read somewhere that I should go with SSL but I would have problems adapting the NIO Server to it.

Any thoughts and recommendations about it? Maybe an example? I would highly appreciate some enlightenment.

Cheers

EDIT:

Forgot to mention that the existing communication is between non-blocking client and non-blocking server through only one SocketChannel

Comment: Possibly via `SSLEngine` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9118367/java-nio-channels-and-tls

Comment: SSLEngine is the way to go, but it is much harder to use than it first appears. Find comments and notes on this by @EJP on stackoverflow and others, as well as in his book.

Comment: Everyone portraits it as a scary scenario, I'll give it a try anyway. I will probably only need to encrypt the communication from Client to Server, should I consider the same approach ?

Comment: No, SSL is two-way encryption. I would just look at the Cipher class for one-way encryption. Encrypt your data, put it into a ByteBuffer, send it, receive it, get it out of the ByteBuffer, use Cipher to decrypt it, ...

Comment: I will go with EJP's advice for now and if I'm required later to encrypt both ways I'll stick my head into SSLEngine. I'll update this post in a few days. Thank you all

Comment: Ok, I got a bit confused now. It seems that I have specifically to add Asymmetric Encryption, but to achieve that both ways are encrypted and I have to figure out a way to distribute the keys right?