# java equivalent to c# sslstream (without tcp)

Tags: java, ssl

I'm trying to create an NFC based communication between my phone and my pc using an arduino. For that I implemented an service in java which provides an Input- and OutputStream for binary based communication.
To encrypt the communication I'm using the C# SslStream on my pc to act as server. It can be created with any stream type (not only tcp). Does java also has an equivalent because its SSLSocket seems to work with tcp based communication only, doesn't it? I just want to use the Input- and OutputStream and encrypt the communication.

thanks in advance

Comment: check [SSLEngine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLEngine.html). [Here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/nio/java-nio-ssl-example/) is an example using NIO and SSLEngine. Similar discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9118367/java-nio-channels-and-tls).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CipherInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/CipherInputStream.html) and [CipherOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/CipherOutputStream.html) to enrypt Input and Output stream respectively. Both of these classes have constructors that accept `InputStream` and `OutputStream` so you can initialise these from existing streams.

[Here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/crypto/encrypt-decrypt-file-stream-with-des/) is an example of how to encrypt/derypt the streams using `Cipher` and `Key`.